# How to merge unknown number of tables together in sqlite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a `sqlite` database, `database_all`.

The `database_all` contains many `tables` of which some are `data_table` and some are `id_table`s.

The `data_table`s look like this:

```
  index  GenderId  EducationId
      1         1            1
      2         2            2
      3         2            1
```

and the `id_table`s look like this:

```
dim.Gender:
  Id Name
   1    F
   2    M

dim.Education:
  Id  Name
   1  High
   2   Low
```

Is there a way, to `revalue` **all** the columns that contain the string `Id` (the number of the columns is unknown) with the values that correspond to the specific `Id` value from the respective `id_table`  ?

The desired output should look like:

```
      index  GenderId  EducationId
          1         F         High
          2         M         Low
          3         M         High
```

Comment: Are you simply looking for `JOIN`?

Comment: yes, but an iterative JOIN

Comment: Put all the joins in a view to avoid having to repeat them in multiple queries (Or just use the relevant ones in each query)

Comment: @Shawn I am not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: Do you know what a view is?

Comment: @Shawn no, i dont

Comment: It's basically a way to give a name to a saved select statement that can then be used like any other table. Idea is you have one that does all the mapping of id numbers to appropriate names, and then use it so you don't have to keep doing all the joins in each individual query. https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html for more.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly, you need to find a way to analyze the queried table structure and automatically link its columns to the corresponding value table, right ?

I think this is not possible without programming so I didn't look into this so much...

but you might find some answers using pragmas.

```
select x.name, y.name from sqlite_master x, pragma_table_info(x.name) y;
```

this will dynamically give you the a full tables-to-columns mapping.

hope this helps